# How do I get the custom properties of a file in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

We have uploaded a file to Google Drive with some additional properties
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/get

I would like to access these properties using Google Apps Script but I cannot find it in the API
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file

Is there an alternative method or have I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

Properties are not supported currently on Apps Script. You may like to integrate with Drive API as an external Rest API: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/external_apis